# Nice way to avoid DivideByZero exception

Tags: c#

I'm trying to divide a number of values and was wondering what would be the best way to check if one of the values is 0 or not.  Usually I use something like

```
var somevar = (somevalue1 != 0 || somevalue2 != 0)?somevalue1 / somevalue2:0;
```

I have to check a lot of values so was wondering if there is a nicer, smarter way of doing this.

Comment: You could always create a method - then you only do the check in a single place.

Comment: You don't need to check if `somevalue1` is 0, dividing 0 by something is of course legal. Dividing *by* 0 is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to check the denominator to prevent a divide by zero.

So

`var somevar = somevalue2 != 0 ? somevalue1 / somevalue2 : 0;`

is much nicer, assuming 0 is a good default.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way without checking and without exception handling from your side.
This is mathematically maybe not the correct way and it is resource consuming but just for the info: you could always use float values and afterwards cut them to integers.

**"Floating-point arithmetic overflow or division by zero never throws an exception, because floating-point types are based on IEEE 754 and so have provisions for representing infinity and NaN (Not a Number)."** (Microsoft)

So you can easily check afterwards if you got a DivideByZero without an exception (via infinite constant). Should be more readable.

```
// This will return "true".
bool isIninity = Double.IsInfinity(3.0 / 0) ?  "true" : "false");
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I edited your post to compile by removing the "true" and "false" strings. I could have also just removed the double quotes.